# grouping rows with the id using a join mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

say for example i have a tables called table1 and table2;

```
table1{q_id,q_text,date},
table2{a_id,q_id,a_text}
```

I run a join query on both tables like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.q_id = table2.q_id
```

i would get data like this

```
q_id     q_text    date   a_id   q_id   a_text
 1      sometext    ..     13      1    someanswer  
 1      sometext2   ..     67      1    someanswet2
```

because thier will be a one to many relationship between the two tables
thier could be a lot of a_ids for one q_id
i wanted to make a query to put all the a_ids that have the same q_id into the same row.
if you get what i mean. so the both rows above have he same q_id so i want them to be in the same row. thanks

Comment: You might be looking for [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: I don't what you mean by "same row" -- which row's data do you want? One row can't have two different entries for the same field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.q_id,table1.q_text,table1.date,table2.a_id,table2.a_text
    -> FROM table1
    -> LEFT JOIN table2
    -> ON table1.q_id = table2.q_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT table1.q_id,table1.q_text,table1.date,table2.a_id,table2.a_text, group_concat(table2.a_id SEPARATOR ',') as a_ids
-> FROM table1
-> LEFT JOIN table2
-> ON table1.q_id = table2.q_id
-> GROUP BY table1.q_id
```

using group_concat and separator ','